# When I send SMS, sometimes result code = 0. What does that code mean?

Tags: android, sms

```
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(
                mDests[i], mServiceCenter, messages,
                sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
```

In my SmsReceiver (sentIntents) sometimes I receive `getResultCode() = 0`.

According to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

It means `STATUS_ON_ICC_FREE`. But I can't understand what it is.
When it is returned - SMS are not sent.

What does this mean and how to fix it? What is the reason for `STATUS_ON_ICC_FREE`?

Comment: Good question :\. This website lists a sample: http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/SimSmsInterfaceManager.java.html which catches that return value. ICC is your SIM-card, and what they do when they catch that message is remove something from the SIM. Maybe the SIM-card is full? (even their reference to TS 51.011 10.5.3 doesn't actually answer any questions ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just comparing result code to the wrong constant. [`SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendMultipartTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.app.PendingIntent%3E%29) Javadoc clearly states about the possible values returned by the `getResultCode()` in the `sentIntents` broadcast:

```
The result code will be Activity.RESULT_OK for success, or one of these errors:
RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
```

In my opinion `STATUS_ON_ICC_xxx` constants were added to the public API by mistake since they are used only by hidden methods of the SmsManager class: `copyMessageToIcc`, `deleteMessageFromIcc` etc.

**UPDATE**

However this doesn't explain why do you receive `0` from `getResultCode()`. As neither of these constant is equal to zero (`Activity.RESULT_CANCEL = 0` but there is no mention of it in the `SmsManager` javadoc). [Quick search](http://androidxref.com/source/search?q=sentIntent.send&project=frameworks) through Android Sources also doesn't give any clue were `0` could come from.

One possibility could be that some other application catch the `sentIntent` broadcast and call `setResultCode` explicitly. However I was sure up to now that it's impossible in Android to prevent the SMS from being sent at the application level.

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc says `Free space (TS 51.011 10.5.3 / 3GPP2 C.S0023 3.4.27).`. The [3GPP2 specifications](http://www.3gpp2.org/public_html/specs/CS0023-0.pdf) say
[image: 3GPP2 C.S0023 3.4.27 status]

I don't know anything about SMS, but from what I understand, this "free space" is opposed to the "used space" (`xx1` that actually defines statuses such as 001 received & read ; 011 receveid & to be read ; etc.)

I would says this status does not mean anything...

In the Android code, I have found only one reference to `STATUS_ON_ICC_FREE`:  `deleteMessageFromIcc()` updates the message with this status when the message has successfully been deleted from the SIM card (aka ICC)

Answer (score 0):

You write that you use the following to send a text:  
`smsManager.sendTextMessage(destination, null, message, null, null);`

Why are you not using the sentIntent parameter which can tell you if your message was accepted by the network?

From the documentation:

sentIntent  if not NULL this PendingIntent is broadcast when the message is successfully sent, or failed. The result code will be `Activity.RESULT_OK` for success, or one of these errors:

```
RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE
RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF
RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU
```

[sms](http://whatdoessmsmean.com/)